# Accessing Postgres on Linux from Python using turbodbc

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, odbc

I'm trying to read large amounts of data from Postgres on Linux via Python.  SQL Alchemy is unacceptably slow.  turbodbc https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc bills itself as being fast, but seems to require an ODBC source, which is Windows, not Linux, AFAIK.  (The Postgres FTP site has only .dlls for ODBC.)  Yet, it claims Linux / Postgres compatibility.

How do I access Postgres on Linux via turbodbc or any other ODBC?

Comment: I would suggest to go with the most used Python PostgreSQL adapter [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/). Just follow the instructions on how to install it on the linked site.

Comment: The problem is that psycopg2 returns lists of tuples, without any of the type or field information, forcing you to reconstruct field names by hand before going to numpy.

Comment: Never used ODBC on the Linux but there is `odbc-postgresql` package in the list...

Comment: Check the [Psycopg `cursor.description` property](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.description) for returned columns info.

Answer (score 1):

turbodbc works with PostgreSQL and Linux. This requires the packages `unixodbc` and `odbc-postgresql` to be installed. Then you need to set up a data source according to PostgreSQL's specifications.

The one issue here is that it won't be blazingly fast. Turbodbc is just an efficient way to communicate with the ODBC driver, basically exploiting bulk operations. However, the ODBC driver freely available for PostgreSQL itself is pretty slow. There is not much turbodbc can do about this.

I'd recommend [psycopg2](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2) or [asyncpg](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg) (the latter requires Python 3.5, but is indeed very fast).